How to build a hero section with a responsive image and add text on top?
this is probably a beginner's question but I'm struggling to make the main img of my hero section responsive, when I use the background-image property together with cover it kind of works but the image is just cutting or zooming instead of shrinking and that's not what I want to reach.
The ideal situation would be to use HTML and CSS to have a hero section with an image convering all the viewport with text on top of which I guess it can be done with some relative/absolute positioning, but the hard part for me is that one since when I decrease the browser size I can only get it to zoom out and out with the cover property, etc, and it becomes fixed when I use widht and height set to 100%
Can this be done? any resources or a guide?

show us what you have so far with a snippet here

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

For a hero section which needs to fit devices of all shapes and sizes, you cannot avoid cropping its background image (unless you prefer to distort it), but you can control which parts of the image are cropped and which part is retained. You do this by:

choosing a focal point in the image – a point in the image which must remain visible,
calculating the location of the focal point as a percentage of the width and height of the image
specifying this location in a background-position style rule.

For example, let’s start with this image:

For a narrow portrait crop we want to keep the shepherd, and for a short landscape crop we want to keep both the sheep and the head of the shepherd. So for our focal point we will choose the spot 47% of the distance across from the left edge, and 76% of the way down from the top edge. The styles we need to use on the element with our background image are therefore:
background-size: cover;
background-position: 47% 76%;

Now let’s see how this works as a hero section. Run this snippet, and after doing so, use the full page link to test the responsiveness, by adjusting the size of your browser window, or using your browser’s responsive design mode.


body {
  margin: 1em;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  background: #eee;
}

.hero {
  margin: -1rem -1rem 1rem;
  height: 100svh;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 3em;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #3a3f2d;
  background-image: url(http://picsum.photos/id/699/1280/720);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 47% 76%;
}
<section class="hero">Title here</section>

<section>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas tempor nunc mauris, sit amet placerat tortor lobortis dapibus. Nam lectus eros, maximus ac magna vel, congue consequat eros. Fusce id pretium diam. Cras sit amet pharetra ante. Sed quis commodo quam, vel facilisis ipsum. Vestibulum sodales iaculis arcu, et fringilla nisi ullamcorper sed. Donec interdum sit amet est non accumsan. Donec non augue feugiat, fermentum nunc non, convallis est. Cras vel ligula nec odio faucibus ultricies. Sed vulputate tortor eget pretium convallis. Cras interdum elit eget mi porta suscipit. Morbi ut velit diam. Etiam finibus eros et efficitur rutrum. Quisque viverra metus ac eleifend imperdiet. Quisque pretium ut purus vitae tempus. Duis varius risus congue velit faucibus, sed interdum purus consectetur.
  </p>
  <p>
    Cras volutpat velit non mi sagittis condimentum. Cras tempor aliquet turpis sed pretium. Nunc aliquet sodales turpis quis ultrices. Duis auctor accumsan enim, quis maximus ex malesuada a. Donec a felis ut erat tempus euismod non vel neque. Proin lectus massa, sagittis at imperdiet nec, consequat ut neque. Sed vel placerat neque, vel varius urna. Vivamus interdum euismod urna a accumsan. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.
  </p>
  <p>
    Nulla rhoncus aliquam mauris, eu pretium dolor auctor in. Maecenas a sollicitudin dolor, eget commodo quam. Proin et dui sed ligula vulputate egestas. Quisque eget augue vitae purus placerat pharetra. Aliquam rhoncus convallis lorem, sed facilisis odio blandit scelerisque. Vivamus viverra urna ac nulla interdum, eget ullamcorper leo maximus. Mauris nec feugiat enim. Nam congue, dui sit amet vestibulum posuere, leo mauris fermentum lorem, eget bibendum velit nunc quis leo.
  </p>
</section>



The same technique can be applied to HTML <img> tags by using object-fit: cover and object-position.

Thanks a lot  you gave me a great explanation, so just to clarify unless I sacrifice the image and let it be distorted the best approach is to set a focal point and go from there?

Yes, unless your hero section can have a fixed aspect ratio across all devices, which is unlikely.

Negative margins? I don't like that.

@DavidWeber those are not really essential to the solution to begin with; plus that's really rather opinion-based.

@CBroe No, it's not opinion based - using negative margins is an anti-pattern. It leads to unpredictable layout behaviours, cross browser compatibility issues and complicated maintenance over time.

Negative margins are permitted in the spec, I use them frequently, and have never had any issues with them.
